# Fantasy Premier League API data Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Has anyone worked to get data set for Fantasy Premier League API?
I found the API https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/

I am unable to get data into the Tables, not sure how to transform the data.

Comment: Not sure what do you want to achieve here, but the data is in JSON format, try to convert it into whatever you want to translate it to.

Comment: I am trying to get the data on Power BI from this API link, but not sure how to transform data to load into tables on Power BI

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was having the same issue. In case you're still looking for a solution, here's how I was able to get data for the players:

1. Add Web source using the API link you've included.
2. In the Power Query Editor - Query Settings > Applied Steps, delete all automatic steps except the first step ("Source")
3. Go to "elements" row, select "List" ("elements" = players. if you're looking for data on teams instead, do the same steps but go to the "teams" row)
4. Right click "List" at the top of column 2, and click "To Table". Click "Ok"
5. To the right of "Column1" at the top, there should be an expand button. Click that and click "Ok"
6. This is likely the data you're looking for. You can now reorganize this data however you like and apply it.